# Is $f'(z)$ defined on $A\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, if $f_n'\to f'$ uniformly?

Tags: complex-analysis

A recall the following theorem: Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions defined on $A$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $K$ be an compact set in $A$. If $f_n(z)$ converges uniformly to $f(z)$ on $K$, then ($f(z)$ is holomorphic on $A$ and) $f'_n(z)$ converges uniformly to $f'(z)$ on $K$.

**Question**: When reading the last sentence, I doubt if it's correct to say that $f'(z)$ too is defined on $A$, or should it be on $K$?

Comment: Since $f$ is holomorphic on $A$,  $f'$ is holomorphic on $A$, so $f'$ is defined on $A$.

Comment: @Jennifer Thanks! How do you know that $f'$ is holomorphic on $A$, if $f$ is that? I mean, where did you get this from?

Comment: Well I assumed $A$ to be open, $f$ holomorphic on $A \iff f$ analytic on $A$. And so you take the derivative of the analytic serie on $A$, and with the same equivalence $f'$ is holomorphic.

Comment: @Jennifer Wow. Yes, sorry $A$ should be an open set. I thought those words were synonymous, so I didn't have to worry about their precise meaning. But I think I get it. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some detail missing in your recollection.

With your setup, let $A$ be the unit disc, $K = \{ 0 \}$ and $f_n(z) = nz$. Then $f_n$ converges uniformly on $K$ to $f(0) = 0$, (but nowhere else), and it hardly makes sense to talk about $f'(0)$.

You need to assume that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $A$, or at least that $f_n$ converges uniformly on *every* compact subset $K \subset A$ for the rest to make sense (and be true).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I should have written "Let $K$ be _any_ compact set in $A$". Is $f_n\to f$ uniformly on (every compact subset) $K$ same as saying $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $A$?

Comment: @Hopeless Uniformly on $A$ is stronger than uniformly on every compact subset $K$ of $A$. Example: take $A$ as the unit disc, and $f_n(z) = z^n$, then $f_n$ converges uniformly (to $0$) on every compact subset of the disc, but not on the disc itself